# Explicit syntax for select xxx from table1,table2

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a select statement

```
select someFields from table1,table2
```

which is a cartesian join, right? What's the explicit syntax for such a join. Searching the web for `,` isn't yielding much luck.

Comment: you mean you can't find any pages with commas? LOL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cartesian join aka [cross-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join):

```
SELECT somefields FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

is a part of ANSI standard SQL:1992.